# What's the fastest way to query Global Shop Solutions from SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, linked-server, global-shop-solutions

I have data in GSS that I need to query from SQL Server. Using `OPENQUERY` is proving to be extremely slow (50 seconds to retrieve only ~4000 rows). Is there a faster way?

Example query, with GSS set up as a linked server using Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers:

```
SELECT     
    ORDER_NO
FROM         
    OPENQUERY(
        GSS, 
        'SELECT 
            Order_No
        FROM ORDER_HEADER 
        WHERE RECORD_TYPE = ''A'''
    )
```

I've also tried using the following query, but it is ridiculously slow: `select * from [GSS].[DBName]..[TableName]`

Linked Server:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  LinkedServer [GSS]    Script Date: 11/30/2022 8:51:50 AM ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'GSS', @srvproduct=N'GSS', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'GSS'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'GSS',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'REMOTEUSER',@rmtpassword='########'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'GSS', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Comment: What details am I missing in this question?

Comment: If it is a Linked Server, why can't you simply do `SELECT * FROM GSS.DBName.schemaname.TableName` instead of using OpenQuery?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock that's what I was thinking as well, but when I try to do that I get this error: `Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "GSS". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema.`

Comment: Can you script out your linked server.

Comment: @Stu yea I'm able to do that. Do you want me to post it in the question?

Comment: Yes edit your question and add the definition it might be useful.

Comment: @Stu ok I've added the script.

Comment: @Stu I figured out how to do the linked server query: `select * from [GSS].[DBName]..[TableName]`. This works, but is also painfully slow.

Comment: How fast is the query run directly on GSS?
And... what is GSS under the covers?

Comment: Have you tried creating a view in sql server `SELECT * FROM ` linked server and then `SELECT * FROM myview WHERE RecordType = 'A'`?

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords it's much faster when run directly in Actian Zen 14, which is like the "SSMS" of GSS. GSS is the software we use to do all our transactions and store data. It stands for Global Shop Solutions.